# Date Check Constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_STUDENT
(STUDID NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
ZIP VARCHAR2(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ZIPCODE(ZIP),
REGISTRATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE > TO_DATE('1-JAN-2000 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')))
```

What is wrong in this, please help. I am getting error: 'missing right parenthisis'

Comment: If you want the foreign key defined inline, remove the `FOREIGN KEY` like this: `ZIP VARCHAR2(5) REFERENCES ZIPCODE(ZIP),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES` check.

You want [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ebff):

```
  create table zipcode
(
  zip varchar2(5) primary key
);

CREATE TABLE TEMP_STUDENT
(STUDID NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
ZIP VARCHAR2(5),
 REGISTRATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE > TO_DATE('1-JAN-2000 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')),
constraint foreign key REFERENCES ZIPCODE(ZIP));
```

Comment: zipcode existed, but primary key was not defined, it worked, thanks.

Comment: @HariChaudhary ah yes.  So when you use a foreign key reference it has to point to a unique/ primary key field.